# Socket IO - how to configure and connect to netty socket io server on a secure domain

Tags: java, ssl, https, socket.io

I need some help with doing netty socket io over https.  I have got it to in my local env but not on a server with secure domain. The server starts but client isn't able to connect. Tried by starting the socket server with IP as well as domain name. For the server to start with domain name as hostname value in **setHostname** method, I added an entry in /etc/hosts file as following

**127.0.0.1   localhost example.com**

Socket server started by giving example.com as hostname but client isn't able to connect using the same hostname over https as following

```
var socket = io.connect('https://example.com:10443')
```

Tried with options - **{ secure: true, reconnect: true, rejectUnauthorized : false }** too but the same issue.

On server side my configuration is as following

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setHostname("example.com");
configuration.setPort(10443);
configuration.setKeyStorePassword("mypassword");
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keystore.jks");
configuration.setKeyStore(stream);
```

The jsk file was created using **keytool** command for the same domain (example.com)

Is there something more to be done for the port - 10443 to be used by the socket server? Or is there any other configuration to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution! I had not mentioned that the domain was set up on cloudflare. Here the issue was with the port I used - 10443. It's not supported by cloudflare. Changed it to 8443 and it worked!

For those who come across this, please find [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-) the list of supported ports that Cloudflare work with. May save much of your time unlike me.

Also, please note that I used my public IP as hostname in setHostname() method so that I don't need anything added in my hosts file. Then gave the actual domain name with https on client side to connect to the server. That's it. Thank you all!

Sandeep